# iOS8 UISplitViewController: who should be the delegate?

Tags: swift, ios8

Until iOS7 the documentation recommends to set the detail view controller as the UISplitViewController delegate.

With the new API `showDetailViewController` the detail view controller is deallocated and reallocated every time, so it cannot be the Split delegate anymore. Which object is now candidate to be the best delegate?

Comment: Please ask your second question as a separate question. Stack Overflow doesn’t handle combined questions that well.

Comment: If you create a new Project in Xcode and select 'Master Detail Application', you get a boiler-plate project with SplitViewController. You will notice that it's actually AppDelegate which is assigned to be the delegate for SplitViewController. I think that's the proposed approach by Apple now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use the root view controller that contains the split view controller as the delegate. It owns the split view controller, so it would make sense for it to respond to messages from the split view controller.

Comment: Thank you Zev. And if the Split is the root view controller, it is the delegate of itself, do you think is it ok?

Comment: Yes, but you can avoid subclassing and use composition instead by using [view controller containment](http://www.objc.io/issue-1/containment-view-controller.html). Kind of up to you where you want that code. It can definitely be its own delegate.